# Subscribe not available after creating Observable with ' of ' operator (Needed forRoot and singleton service)

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs

I am forced to use Promises with Observables here because when loading data in an Angular app, it requires you to use APP_INITIALIZER with a returned promise.  That is why I am creating an observable inside a promise. After debugging it to see why my data is not loading into tables I have seen that my instance data member this.tableDataObs has nothing to subscribe to when being called at a later time using the method getTableModelDataSource(tableName: string) and I can't understand WHY? It does have value inside the promise. What is going on?

```
export class UiDataService {
    tableDataObs: Observable<TableModel[]>;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
        this.tableDataObs = new Observable<TableModel[]>();
    }

    loadTableData(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.httpClient
                .get('/assets/data/tables.json')
                .map((tables: JSON) => {
                const tableModels: TableModel[] = this.createTableModels(tables);
                this.tableDataObs = of(tableModels); // tableModels has array value here
                // this.tableDataObs.subscribe(s => console.log(s)); again subscribing to observable here returns array 
            })
            .subscribe(() => {
                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    }

    getTableModelDataSource(tableName: string): TableModelDataSource {
        this.tableDataObs.subscribe(s => console.log(s)); // this.tableDataObs has nothing to subscribe to here? WHY?
    ...
    }
```

the load data call happens from my SharedModule that is imported into my AppModule

```
imports ...

export function tableFactory(provider: UiDataService) {
    return () => provider.loadTableData();
}


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    entryComponents: [...],
    providers: [
        ...
        UiDataService,
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: tableFactory, deps: [UiDataService], multi: true },
    ],
    exports: [
      ...
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

and the getTableModelDataSource method call happens in a component with a mat table that needs a datasource

Comment: Which version of `rxjs` you using ?

Comment: thanks for you response Ethan. I tried it with 6.0.0 and then upgraded to 6.5.2 thinking that might be the problem as well. Same result. I am using rxjs-compat .

Comment: Could you provide us with the code where the getTableModelDataSource and  loadTableData are called? Another thing that i want to point out is that you're using the deprecated http and if you could please give a bigger picture so that we couldnt help you to the best we can, since i think making promise that has an observable that has a sideeffect in it, is not required.

Comment: Thanks Qellson. Sure. I am simply calling this service getTableModelDataSource from my component that needs the datasource for a mat table . this.tableImmediateOngoingFutureDataSource = this.uiDataService.getTableModelDataSource('tableImmediateOngoingFuture');

Comment: let me give you a code sample of the loadTableData call. just a sec.

Comment: Hi @Qellson. I have updated my question to give you a better idea of how this is all fitting together from a bigger perspective. If you google APP_INITIALIZER and "preloading data angular app " you will find several examples that are similiar to what I am doing. Weird thing is I thought I had this working at one time and I can't figure out what has changed, but I do notice what I have shown here that seems to localize where the problem is now.

Comment: Having subscribe inside a normal method, behaves like an normal method call i.e it tries to subscribe the data at the time of method call but has no data at that time. Can you have the subscriber at constructor or at ngOnInit

Comment: The longshot is, if the function gets called like you are calling it here, that you're accidently instantiating 2 instances of the same service, one has the data, the other doesnt. We can test that by console.loging a string in the service constructor and see if its called 2 times.

Comment: yes, loadTableData is called and tableModels has a value of array of tables that I am expecting and it gets converted into the Observable inside the promise with the 'of ' keyword. However, when I call the getTableModelDataSource in the ngOnInit of my component that needs the datasource for its mat table, when I subscribe to the same observable, it does not have a _subscribe property like it did inside the promise.

Comment: @Qellson, can you explain the two instsances theory more. What is causing this the way it is written?

Comment: yes, it is getting called twice

Comment: where is this coming from?

Comment: Ive seen this happening in lazyloading, when you inject a service in a lazyloaded module and you already instantiated when the app was loaded, that lazyloaded module instantiates the service one more time and by that you have two of the same service that have different data set.

Comment: hmm... let me test some stuff out. I will move this to my app module to hopefully avoid this lazy loaded problem and see what happens. this may have been why it way working a while back and now it isn't. we'll see. I'll give you credit if this works.

Comment: Hope you get it working! Happy coding :)

Comment: @JohnStafford Angular.io related docs for your problem https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: why not use toPromise Rxjs function?

Comment: @Qellson, you made me realize something that I did likely change. This module was using the forRoot a while back when it probably was working. I scrapped it. That is probably what happened. It's getting late here. I'll tackle this tomorrow. Thanks again. Eliseo, the promise part works just fine . I have verified that by getting data in my load function. I think Qellson is on the right track based on the consoles printing out twice and my previous use of forRoot when this was working.

Comment: @Qellson that was it man! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Comment: Just for everyone viewing this and running into a similar situation, I DID NOT move the app init stuff into the app module to avoid lazy loading but just kept it in the child module (SharedModule) and used forRoot on this module like was suggested to achieve a singleton service.